# JQuery change text displayed after 5 seconds, twice

Tags: jquery

I am calling this function to show a loading popup window:

```
LoadModalBody('<h2 align="center">Loading...</h3><p align="center"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x"></i></p>');
```

the function itself, basically creates a div element and displays the data inside the div

When I call the function, I want to be able to change the `Loading...` text after 5 seconds, and then change it again after another 5 seconds.

Is this possible to do outside of the function?

Comment: How about adding an intervel 5 seconds, assign an id to your `h2`, and then change your html in interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LoadModalBody('<h2 id="headingLoading" align="center">Loading...</h3><p align="center"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x"></i></p>');

setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('headingLoading').innerHtml = 'New Text 1';
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('headingLoading').innerHtml = 'New Text 2';
    }, 5000);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: perfect, i wasn't sure whether it would change because its inside a function but i guess thinking about it its just an element that displays on screen so its accessible... is it possible to create a loop so i can setup pre-defined words to show and it'll loop around once finished?

Comment: sure it is, create an array with words, save the index and every 5 second increment the index by one and set innerHTML to array[index], and if index >= array.length, reset the array to 0 to loop around